# content management system and document management system

Tags: content-management-system, dms, query-by-example

If you want to look at the differences in the **content management system** and the **document management system** in the real world, what is the **best** **example**?

Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between the content management and document management system. Name of both the services or tools seems to be same but there is a difference
**CMS ( Content Management System)**
The content management system is the tool which is used to maintain the content of a website or the application. Let me elaborate you in details
**Have you ever create a website?**  A website is developed in Wordpress or in different things like Shopify, Magento etc. This kind of things are included in a content management system

**Document Management System (DMS)** 
Document management system is used in the business/company or for individuals.
In DMS all the papers or documents are converted into the digital form by scanning them and saved all the documentation in the cloud server which will never be lost or theft.
All the business document are secured.

Answer (score 0):

Content management systems vary from document management systems in one key area – the type of information they manage. 
Document management system is designed specifically for data contained in structured documents and files like Word, PowerPoint, Excel spreadsheets, PDF, and other popular formats. Their purpose is primarily to digitize and archive files and track and manage new documents throughout their lifecycle, as they are written, revised, and updated. Many of them include advanced imaging and scanning capabilities (for digitization of hard copy files), that can’t be found in most content management systems.

Content management systems, on the other hand, are more about the logical organization and improved accessibility of various types of structured and unstructured electronic information. This includes not only the kinds of files that are managed by document management applications but a broader range of digital assets. For example, audio, video, Flash, and multimedia files, as well as raw data collected from various third-party Internet sources.